# How to make devise not require authentication for home page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have `before_action :authenticate_user!` in the application controller, which is very efficient because it applies to all controllers but there's one page (home page) that should be available without login.

Is there a way to keep `before_action :authenticate_user!` in `application_controller.rb` (for the sake of DRY) and make an exception to allow access to just `home#home` to be available without authentication?

Notes:

- we could obviously remove `before_action :authenticate_user!` from the application controller and place it in all controllers *but* for `'home#home'` (the downside to this is it's not very DRY)
- just a side note, but I'm not exactly sure why the `/users/sign_in` url is even accessible (something in devise must make it so, but I'm not sure where that mechanic lives or what it is exactly - perhaps if I found it I could add more routes to it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to skip the `before_action` using `skip_before_action`

In the controller for that page put

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:home]
```

This specifies it just for that one action, if all the pages in that controller need to be skipped you can just use

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
```